# Remove related table from Peewee query

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I am using Peewee as ORM with Flask and I have some tables like that:

```
class Table1(Model):
    column1 = TextField(null=True)
    column2 = TextField(null=True)

class Table2(Model):
    column3 = TextField(null=True)
    column4 = TextField(null=True)
    table1 = ForeignKeyField(Table1, backref="related_table")
```

And I have a query like that;

`model_to_dict(Table2.select())`

I am getting following result;

```
[
    {
        "column3" : "...",
        "column4" : "...",
        "related_table" : {
            "column1" : "...",
            "column2" : "..."
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

But I don't want to getting related table. That's what I want;

```
[
    {
        "column3" : "...",
        "column4" : "..."
    }
    ...
]
```

I know I can get the result with that :

`model_to_dict(Table2.select(Table2.column3, Table2.column4))`

But if there is many columns, I think it is kinda annoying.
The question is, is there any better way to get the result without related tables or any other columns?

Comment: Please share the code you are using to generate that output

Comment: I've already write down there, the output is coming from `Table2.select()` query.

Comment: `Table2.select()` returns a `ModelSelect` object. Your output shows a list of dicts.

Comment: Ok, I added `model_to_dict()` function. But you missing the main point which is how I get a model list without related tables.

Comment: If your code tries to access nested/related objects (which `model_to_dict()` does by default unless you set `recurse=False`), peewee will automatically fetch and populate those objects/values. This is how most ORMs work. If you just want raw/flat data, then do [something like](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#retrieving-row-tuples-dictionaries-namedtuples) `Table2.select().dicts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @booshong, this solution is working:

```
model_to_dict(Table2.select(), recursive=False)
```